# If R is a local ring, then its maximal left-ideal is a left and right ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have been trying to prove the statement in the title, however I seem to get stuck at a certain point. Let $M$ be the maximal left-ideal of $R$. Then consider $M.r$ for $r \in R$. If $M.r \neq R$, we have that $M.r \subseteq M$. Now if this assumption would be true, we would have that $M$ is a right ideal as well. However when trying to prove that $M.r \neq R$ for all $r \in R$ I don't get very far. I know that if we assume equality, one would get $m.r=1$ for one $m \in M$. However I don't know how to go from here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove if a non-trivial ring $R$ has a unique maximal left ideal $J$ , then $J$ is two-sided and is also the unique maximal right ideal in $R$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243171/prove-if-a-non-trivial-ring-r-has-a-unique-maximal-left-ideal-j-then-j-i)

Comment: @Rick Look at your proposed dupe: the poster says "i can prove it is two sided but I can't prove uniqueness" and the solver posts an answer that proves uniqueness.  That is  not helpful for the question asked here.  But nevertheless it's a good thing to link as a related question.

Comment: This is [also related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2355049/29335) but interpreting it a a duplicate requires a bit of mental contortion that seems excessive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R$ has one maximal left ideal, then it is the Jacobson radical.  Do you know the Jacobson radical is two-sided?

---

Different idea:

Lemma: a local ring has only trivial idempotents. (Proof: if $e$ were a nontrivial idempotent, then how could $Re$ and $R(1-e)$ both be contained in the maximal left ideal?)

Hint: Now if $mr=1$ for some $m\in M$, $r\in R$, then $rm$ is an idempotent...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Would I then do the following: since $rm$ is idempotent it has to be trivial and therefore $rm=1$, which implies $1 \in M$ and is therefore a contradiction?

Comment: @HenryMeyer correct.  Then your original reasoning that $Mr\subseteq M$ holds together than you're done.